# Expression Expected

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, compiler-errors

Im getting a build error with the following code...

```
Private Property GridViewSortDirection() As String

    Get
        Return If(TryCast(ViewState("SortDirection"), String), "ASC")
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        ViewState("SortDirection") = value
    End Set

End Property
```

It is happening on the following line...

```
Return If(TryCast(ViewState("SortDirection"), String), "ASC")
```

Error returns...

Error   11  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TPSupport\main\UserControls\grid.ascx.vb(192): error BC30201: Expression expected.

Any Idea's

Thanks

Its a convert from c#

```
private string GridViewSortDirection
{
   get { return ViewState["SortDirection"] as string ?? "ASC"; }
   set { ViewState["SortDirection"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: if(ViewState("SortDirection"))
return "ASC"
end if

Comment: i think it doesn't accept returning a condition ... so do the condition and then return the value

Comment: If(TryCast(ViewState("SortDirection"), String), "ASC") - is this such a construct possible? on what compiler? (I cannot get it to compile on VS 2008)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with VB but use of `If` keyword shows that you are doing comparison between result of `TryCast` and `"ASC"`,

Try this way, by using appropriate comparison operator like

```
 Return If(TryCast(ViewState("SortDirection"), String) <> "ASC")
```

Answer (score 0):

What compiler version are you using? I suspect that you inadvertently switched to a version of VB (< 9.0) that doesn’t yet support the conditional operator.